# Probability of dying

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

I have this scenario:

> 10 people with 100% of probability of dying in 1 month.

So I assume that at the end of the month I'm gonna have:

**10 dead people; 

0 alive people.**

I also have this scenario:

> 10 people with 60% of probability of dying in 1 month.

So I can also assume that at the end of the month I'm gonna have:

**6 dead people;

4 alive people.**

Is that correct?

Comment: The mean of $B(10, 0.6)$, binomial distribution with $n=10$ and $p=0.6$, is $6$, but that is, by definition, the outcome in long term. There could be fluctuations in the number of the dead (if you could repeat the scenario, hopefully not).

Answer (score 1):

It is not certain that 6 people will be dead and 4 alive.

That is the most likely outcome, but, you could imagine a very unlucky month where each person died.  The likelihood for each number of deaths is plotted below.

[image]

Comment: It's not "certain", but... is this a scenario that I hope I can have when the month ends?

Comment: Roughly 25% of the time, yes.  But 5 or 7 deaths also have a greater than 20% chance of happening.  But less than 25%.

Comment: Chances are, there will NOT be 6 deaths.  75% of the time it will be a different number.  But it is still the most likely outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you had ten coins each of which came up heads with probability 60% and you flipped them would you always see exactly 6 heads and 4 tails? If the coins were fair (50-50) would you always see just 5 heads and 5 tails?

Comment: Ethan, "exactly 6 heads and 4 tails", no... But it's... **probability**. So you mean it's wrong to assume that numbers (6 dead people and 4 alive people) in the end of the month, right?

Comment: As @turkeyhundt says, 6 dead people is the most probable outcome, but that doesn't mean you're "gonna have" 6 dead people. Anything from 0 dead to 10 dead might happen, with predictable probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of exactly $6$ dead people at the end of the month is:

$$\binom{10}{6}\times(0.6)^6\times(1-0.6)^{10-6}\approx0.25$$

---

More generally, the probability of exactly $n$ dead people at the end of the month is:

$$\binom{10}{n}\times(0.6)^n\times(1-0.6)^{10-n}$$

Comment: Barak, is this a formula? Where those numbers came from? Maybe it's exactly what I'm looking for. Because this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221670/variable-weight-more-than-another-in-probability

Comment: @FelipeM: The first part is a direct answer to your specific question. The second part is (**as noted**) a general formula for $n$ dead people out of $10$ people. Those numbers ($10$ and $0.6$) come from your question (where else would they come from?).

Comment: Did you invent that formula? It's a question with the objective of be a base for me to find out the answer to that question. If you can't see, there's no answer over that one.

Comment: @FelipeM: I did not "invent" that formula, I simply gave you a way to calculate the probability of exactly $n$ dead people out of $10$ people, where the probability to die is $0.6$. Of course, $n$ can be any integer value between $0$ and $10$. If you're looking for the general case of exactly $n$ dead people out of $m$ people, where the probability to die is $p$, then you can simply replace $10$ with $m$ and $0.6$ with $p$ (in that formula above).